# iOS to FTDI Chip Communication

Tags: ios, iphone, bluetooth-lowenergy, serial-communication, ftdi

I want to develop an iOS application which can send serial data from iPhone to FTDI chip-FT231X(vid: '0403', pid: '6015'). I have been looking for this solution for a while but couldn't find anything related to my problem. I am allowed to communicate to FTDI chip using USB or bluetooth. Also please let me know if there is any available device which I can buy to solve my problem.

Comment: If the device supports BLE then you should be able to write an app using Core Bluetooth.  If the device only supports legacy bluetooth (e.g. SPP) and/or you want to use the lightning port then your device will need to be MFi certifiied

Comment: the FT231X is a USB to UART IC. So mostlikely there is no easy way to connect it to an IPhone. Or is this already solved?

Answer (score 1):

The nearest solution I found so far is at here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/2295-arduino-tutorial-integrating-bluetooth-le-and-ios